# Change transition per submit tag in a form with jQuery Mobile

Tags: forms, jquery-mobile, transition

Is it possible that different submit tags in a form in a web site that's using jQuery Mobile (1.3.1) will trigger different transitions and/or directions?

Comment: yes, if you use `changePage()` for all the submit buttons and add a `transition` option to it. That way you could set the transitions your way. hell, you could keep all the transitions in a string and randomize it

Comment: @passionateCoder do I have to use an ajax callback to call changePage()?

Answer (score 0):

Just to throw my towel in. 
Now for the question you've asked, the answer is a **YES**. You can use a randomizing sequence to choose the transition at runtime and pass the URL and the transition to `changePage`, which will redirect you to the url you provided. More at jQM [docs](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/)

Here's a demo of the randomised transitions : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/fpw6B/

Now for your second question - No, you neednt have an `ajax` callback for this to work. When `changePage` is called, this is the operation which happens:

- hides the current page
- takes the URL you provided through your code
- fetches the page **through ajax** (if the url provided is an external page)
- appends it after the current page
- shows the new page

As you can see, it doesnt necessarily need `ajax`.

Hope these answer your questions.